# Android ViewModelProvider.Factory: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class GameViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I'm trying to create a ViewModelFactory for creating my ViewModel.

The factory class is:

```
class GameViewModelFactory(private val application: GameApplication) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(GameViewModel::class.java)) {
            return GameViewModel(application) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

I also tried to extend from `ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(application)` but the result is the same.

And the constuctor of the ViewModel class is:

```
class GameViewModel(private val gameApplication: GameApplication) : AndroidViewModel(gameApplication)
```

The way I'm calling it altogether in my fragment is the following:

```
val remoteViewModelFactory = GameViewModelFactory(GameApplication())
        gameViewModel = ViewModelProviders
                .of(this, remoteViewModelFactory)
                .get(GameViewModel::class.java)
```

The problem comes that it does not seem to get it, and I think it could be because of the `Application` object.
I have already tried to create a singleton in my `GameApplication` class, but it is still the same:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class trate.data.viewmodel.GameViewModel
    at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:199)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:133)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:101)
    at trate.ui.game.GameFragment.onCreate(GameFragment.kt:70)
```

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: If I debug and get into the VieWModelProvider class, I see that it reaches the `AndroidViewModelFactory`class and gets into the `get` create method.
It then tries to return `modelClass.getConstructor(Application.class).newInstance(mApplication)` but then it throws the following `RuntimeException`:

```
result = {NoSuchMethodException@5072} "java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.app.Application]"
 backtrace = {Object[32]@5085} 
 cause = {NoSuchMethodException@5072} "java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.app.Application]"
 detailMessage = "<init> [class android.app.Application]"
 stackTrace = {StackTraceElement[0]@5087} 
 suppressedExceptions = {Collections$EmptyList@5088}  size = 0
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@3232} "class java.lang.NoSuchMethodException"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -2097726229
```

Comment: It feels like it is not using your factory for some reason. Are you sure that's the code that you are executing?

Comment: yes it is, but it never reaches the `create` overridden method in the `GameViewModelFactory`. Is there any other step for using the factory, apart from the one I'm doing it in the code? Maybe I missed something

Comment: @noloman would you like to share your finding?

Comment: CommonsWare is right I was getting the similar error and his suggestion works